# How do you tell Heroku to ignore SqlLite gem in development group

Tags: postgresql, heroku, rubygems

I'm trying to deploy a super simple Sinatra app with a registration form on Heroku.

I'm getting the error

```
Process exited with status 1
2012-09-27T05:59:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

further up the logs in that event, 
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `require':     no such file to load -- dm-sqlite-adapter (LoadError)

my gem file reads like this:

```
group :development do
   gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
end
```

Looking through stack overflow, it seems either heroku isn't choosing the production group or hasn't set up the postgres db? (wild stabs in the dark, please don't laugh at me)

but running this

```
tonto:bpbl willbarker$ heroku addons 
=== serene-sea-9304 Configured Add-ons
heroku-postgresql:dev HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT
```

Shows a postgres db is configured. so, is it running in development mode for some reason? How do i get it to ignore that line?

Comment: What does your `DataMapper.setup` line look like?

Comment: DataMapper::setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/campaign.db")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to set the `DATABASE_URL` [environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) on Heroku.

The error you’re getting is `no such file to load -- dm-sqlite-adapter`, so the file *isn’t* available and the `:development` group in your Gemfile hasn’t been installed, just as you’d want.

When your app comes to setting up Datamapper it uses the line:

```ruby
DataMapper::setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/campaign.db")
```

So it’s looking for an environment variable called `DATABASE_URL` but isn’t finding one, so is falling back on the Sqlite url. This causes Datamapper to try to load `dm-sqlite-adapter` and results in the error you’re getting.

The solution is to make sure that `DATABASE_URL` is set. Try running `heroku config` – you’ll likely not see an entry for `DATABASE_URL`. You should be able to [promote your configured database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#specifying-and-promoting-databases) with the command:

```
$ heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT
```

Comment: Ok, thats working.  Also knowing the heroku config command will help me try and work things out in the future myself - thanks.